# How exactly does a transistor amplify the input current in CE configuration

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, semiconductors

I have gone through tons of forum discussions and videos and books but they all explain in terms of mathematical equations that factor the input by a 'larger than 1' number. What happens physically inside?

Comment: Sounds like a physics question to me.

Comment: @Andyaka but isn't that the base of electronics?

Comment: This can not be explained in a few sentences. But check this page out, here you will find an answer: http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/toc5.htm

Comment: @harishs try physics SE

Comment: @Andy - actually the question seems to be on-topic, as described on the [Help Center > Asking page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as it is about *the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces* (second bullet).

Comment: @Ricardo I'm only suggesting that it is a physics question and might get better answers over there. I've not downvoted or voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is grossly simplified, but I think you're asking for a very simple answer, so take it in the spirit it's offered.

The key lies in the fact that for some semiconductors/junctions,

a) you can talk about majority and minority charge carriers, roughly electrons and holes, depending on whether the material is p-type or n-type.

b) under a broad range of conditions, the product of minority and majority carriers remains constant.

This means that, for the proper materials and junction configurations, such as a bipolar junction transistor (BJT) when you inject a small number of minority carriers, you make a large difference in the total minority population. Let's say you double the minority concentration by adding some current. Since the product of minority and majority carriers remains constant, if you double the number of minority carriers, you must halve the number of majority carriers, which provide current to the device outputs. Since, by definition, minority carriers are in the minority (and by a large proportion in practical devices), a small change in their concentration produces a large change in the concentration of the majority carriers. In other words, the injected current gets amplified.

Like I say, this is the really, really simplified version, and is just one step up from Lies-To-Children. If you need details or a better understanding, you're just going to have to learn to wade through the equations. Sorry.

Comment: I would like to add, that the factor they multiply the input with is derived from a model (often the small-signal model) of the transistor. The model is the approximation used when designing and calculating circuits.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Now I understand. So the transistor just copies the input variation on a larger scale at the output side right?

Comment: Yes - however, the "input variation" is a voltage and the "output side" delivers a current Ic.

Comment: @LvW - Well, carrier concentrations are charges, so changing concentrations is better described in terms of current, at least for BJTs. You're probably thinking of MOSFETs.

Comment: @harishs - Well, close enough. It's better to stick with numbers, since the "whys" of semiconductor doping, potential gradients and carrier concentrations are not exactly intuitive. Let's just say that changes in the input current are amplified to produce changes in the output current. Like I said in the answer, to get into any greater detail means learning how to deal with the equations.

Comment: ..." to get into any greater detail means learning how to deal with the equations.." As I have tried to explain in my contribution - it is a widely spread myth that the collector current of a BJT would be physically controlled by the base current. This false view can be read even in some textbooks. Rather, the BJT is a voltage-controlled device (doesn`t everybody use 0.6...0.7 volts to let a dc current flow?).

Comment: No, this isnt right. The law of mass action applies when you dont have external electron/hole sources or generation (thermal equilibrium). Once you start adding carriers from outside it changes the populations but you no longer have pn=ni^2. This "simplification" isnt "lies to children" territory, its just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Transistors make use of semiconductors. Nowadays it means pretty much exclusively silicon. You have N-type (more electrons) and P-type (less electrons). When you put differently treated pieces of silicon together, you create *junctions* (PN junction, etc.). You can bias (put voltage on) a junction, that makes it either more conductive, or less conductive. You can also apply electrostatic attraction/repulsion on the electrons in the silicon, which again changes conductivity (FET).

---

But as stated in the comments, this cannot possibly fit in a single answer - it's like asking *"What is the topic of this website?"*

I'd suggest starting with the topic of *diodes*.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate a bit to answer your question because I know that some persons will heavily disagree. However, because you have asked "what happens physically inside" my answer is as follows:

The bipolar transistor is a **voltage controlled device** - that means>: The current Ic is determined and controlled by the voltage Vbe - and not by the input current Ib. This is what the famous Shockley equation says. More than that, this view is confirmed in a written form from leading institutions in the US (Berkeley, Stanfore, MIT,...). The well-known equation Ic=beta*Ib cannot say anything about cause and result. It is just a relation - nothing else.

It is absolutely not necessary to go down to the charged carrier level - the voltage-control feature can be justified on circuit level (behaviour of the transistor within a circuit).

And the explanation of the working principle is relatively simple - as long as you know how a pn diode is working: Of course, the basic principle remains unchanged: The emitter emittes electrons (npn case) caused by the voltage VBE, but the majority of the electrons goes not to the base but is attracted by the larger positive voltage of the collector region. That`s all. This description is simplified up to a certain degree but it explains the basic principle.

**EDIT/UPDATE**:
Here are some references:

**Univ. of Berkeley:** 
Ic is determined by the rate of electron injection from the emitter into the base, i.e., determined by VBE. An undesirable but unavoidable side effect of the application of VBE is a hole current flowing from the base, mostly into the emitter. This base (input) current, Ib,
is related to Ic by the common-emitter current gain,

**Stanford Univ.:** 
Conceptual View of an NPN Bipolar Transistor (Active Mode): Device acts as a voltage
controlled current source: VBE controls IC.

**Mass. Inst. of Technology (MIT)**: Bipolar Junction Transistors: basic operation and modeling…
… how the base-emitter voltage, VBE, controls the collector current, IC:...

**Barry Gilbert (Analog Devices) :** 
BJT is a voltage-controlled current-source; the base current is purely incidental (it is best viewed as a „defect“)

**Winfield Hill** (Co-author Art of Electronics):
The physics and formulas are the key: In the case of the transistor we have the solid-state physics resulting in the rigorous Ebers-Moll formulas, with their precise prediction for collector current IC from VBE. Just because you can successfully bias a few BJT circuits with current doesn't meant they're current-controlled devices.

Comment: And I just have to jump in. Voltage and current are RELATED by the Schockley equation, but to assert that one "controls" the other is very hard to justify. It's perfectly possible to drive the base of transistor with a current source, in which case the voltage is completely uncontrolled in the sense you seem to be talking about. In this case, the current is not "controlled" by the voltage - rather, the voltage is produced by the current. Just stick with "related" and stop trying to isolate "cause".

Comment: No - it is not hard to justify. Believe me - I know what I am talking about. As I have mentioned - there are several observations to be made (on circuit level) which prooves voltage control. One of which is the fact that an emitter resistor increases the input resistance (known fact). From theory we know that such an increase indicates VOLTAGE feedback (otherwise the input resistance must reduce). Do you need other justifications?

Comment: May I add another comment regarding "driving the base with a current source". I know - and I even use - this terminology. However, it is a somewhat "sloopy" expression that is not correct. We cannot "pump" a current into any node because each current needs a driving voltage. Hence, what we do is the following: We create a voltage divider using a very large resistor which primarily determines the current ("current source") that goes into another much smaller resistive device (B-E junction). As a result - a voltage is developped across the B-E path which determines the collector current.

Comment: 1) Adding an emitter resistor reduces input conductance (known fact) From there we know that such a decrease indicates Current Feedback. Otherwise conductance must increase. 2) I can easily make a very good current source with an op amp and a few resistors, which will have an extremely high output resistance. If I feed this into the base of a transistor, I have no need whatsoever to calculate the resulting base voltage in order to calculate the collector current. That, as a matter of fact, is why beta is so useful a quantity.

Comment: Sorry - it is not correct. An emitter resistor causes an increase of the input resistance by a factor (1+betaRE). From system theory we know that this is the case for voltage feedback only (another example: Non-inv. opamp stage). In our case: Current controlled voltage-feedback with a loop gain of beta*RE. No doubt about it. Another example: Two gain stages with different beta values (of course, same dc operating point): The voltage gain is equal in both cases - independent on beta!